# What's the difference between "suburb“ and ”suburbs“?

Tags: difference

What's the difference between "suburb" and "suburbs"? Please tell me. Thanks:)

Comment: To get the best answer, you should look these words up in a dictionary and then indicate what about the definitions are not clear.  Otherwise, we have to guess at what differences you are interested in.

Comment: Hello erika999 and welcome to ELL! On this site, we require people asking questions to show they've done some work themselves to find the answer, and to show what they already know. This saves answerers from doing dictionary lookups that the asker could just as easily have done, and from wasting time telling the asker things they already know

Answer (score 1):

A city or town usually has a central part, and further away from that, districts or areas called **suburbs** (plural, see the 's' at the end?) One of these is a **suburb** (singular, no 's' at the end).

[Plural and singular nouns](https://www.ef.co.uk/english-resources/english-grammar/singular-and-plural-nouns/)